# How to pass arrays from model to view?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm just learning ASP.NET MVC 3, And recently I tried a lot of times to pass arrays/lists/ICollections etc. but couldn't. everytime the list was empty.

For example, the current project:

**Model:**

```
public class Video
{
    public int VideoID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**Initializer - Seed:**

```
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        var videos = new List<Video>
        {
            new Video {
                Name = "Video01",
                Tags = new List<string> { "tag1", "tag2" },
        };

        videos.ForEach(s => context.Videos.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

In the view: **I do get the `Name`** property, but the `Tags` are completely empty.

In the debug I get `Tags - Count: 0`.

This is not the first time it happens to me, to be honest it happens every single time when I try to pass those kind of stuff. a bit of info about the project:

*ASP.NET MVC 3, Entity-Framework:Code First, SqlServerCe.4.0.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crean an entity Tag

```
public class Video
{
    public int VideoID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
  public int TagId { get; set; }
  public int VideoId { get; set; }
  public string TagText { get; set; }
}
```

or store tags to one field separated with comma /semicolon or whatever fits for your solution

Answer (score 0):

By default Entity Framework doesn't load associations of an entity, you need to specify it explicitly:

```
var videos = context.Videos.Include("Tags");
```

Comment: Where do I write it? (How can I write it + the video list) and when you say the ef doesn't load associations of an entity, what do you mean by associations?
Thanks

Comment: Actually I misread the question, I assumed the Tags were also EF entities... how did you map the `Tags` collection?

Comment: Kind of a beginner, could you explain what you're asking? I think you mean the model, if so, it's in the question.

Comment: I'd recommend staying away from the magic strings now that 4.1 supports .Include(o=>o.TableName)

Comment: @Ken, what I meant is, how did you specify the mapping between the model and the DB? If you let EF infer it automatically, I don't think it can handle things like a collection of strings (but it can handle a collection of entities)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque How do I actually do it then? could you give me a little bit of guideance / a good reference?